# Trouble integrating ckeditor inside bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

i want to generate a custom textarea inside my bootbox. This is my code

```
function showQuotationBox() {
    bootbox.prompt({
        title: "This is a prompt with a textarea!",
        className: 'ckeditor',
        inputType: 'textarea',
        callback: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    CKEDITOR.replace('textarea');
}
```

But I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined

Normal textarea still appears though. Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't passing the element id or name to `replace()`.  http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace

Comment: I passed the class name inside it. It's still not working.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I have same problem

Comment: @FerhatA I guess no. It is a very old thread but I can help you now if you want.